# Вытащить текст из td

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
#!/usr/bin/Env python3

import urllib.request
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     return response.read()

def parse(html):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
     td = soup.find('td', class_='eMessage')
     print(td.prettify())

def main():
     parse(get_html('http://4inana.ucoz.ru/news/giga_plamja_serdec_ft_aj_man/2014-12-05-108'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Никак не могу добраться до текста. Как вытащить сам текст ?

Comment: До какого текста вы хотите добраться?

Comment: Текст материла , конкретно по этому примеру текст песни ) если перейдете то поймете меня )

Answer (score 0):

Вот так возвращается текст песни:

```
#!/usr/bin/Env python3

import urllib.request
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    td = soup.find('td', class_='eMessage')
    print(td.text.split('}')[1])


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://4inana.ucoz.ru/news/giga_plamja_serdec_ft_aj_man/2014-12-05-108'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```